# Obtener el valor escrito por el usuario con keyup y almacenar el resultado en una variable global

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy intentando guardar en una variable global *(para poder trabajarla y luego hacer append en otro textarea)* el valor de la función keyup y no sé como hacerlo, no se en qué fallo.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var input;
  function getUserInput() {
    $('.user-input').keyup(function(){
      this.value = this.value.toLowerCase();
      var input = $(this).val();
      console.log(input);
    })
  }
  
  input = getUserInput();
  console.log(input);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="user-input" id="contenido-post" placeholder="Tu texto aquí"></textarea>
```

EL primer console.log me muestra todo lo tecleado en el text area, perfecto.
El segundo console.log no me muestra nada. Necesito tener el valor de lo que se escriba en el textarea en la variable input.

Comment: Claro, es que en la función `getUserInput` no estas retornando el valor del input ademas solo estas llamando a la función cuando inicia el programa. de igual manera lo único que haces es obtener lo que se escribe en minúsculas. no te conviene solo hacer el $('textarea').val()?

Answer (score 0):

El código que tienes no se ejecuta de manera secuencial.

`keyup` es un evento. Por lo que cuando se suelte una tecla, se ejecutará la función en la que tienes el primer `console.log`. Genial.

Luego tienes `input = getUserInput();`

Estás asignando a `input` lo que devuelva `getUserInput()`, pero si te das cuenta, esa función no devuelve nada, solo añade al `textarea` la llamada a la función cada vez que tenga lugar un `keyup`.

Al no devolver nada esa función, el segundo `console.log` muestra `undefined`. Porque `input` tiene un valor `undefined`. Es decir, el segundo `console.log` sí está mostrando algo, pero no es lo que esperas.

Otro problema que tienes en el código es que estás redefiniendo `input` dentro de la función del `keyup`. Por lo que el `input` de dentro y el de fuera son distintos.

Mira este código de abajo. Sin redefinir input, estoy actualizando el valor de fuera. Además he puesto un intervalo para que cada 3 segundos haga un `console.log` de `input`.

Ahora si escribes en el textarea, la variable la tienes fuera. Pero el código sigue ejecutando de forma secuencial, así que el `console.log` de fuera de la función seguirá poniendo `undefined`. El del `setInterval` pondrá el valor de input cuando toque. Quizá sea aún `undefined` pero si has escrito en el `textarea` será ese valor.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var input;
  function getUserInput() {
    $('.user-input').keyup(function(){
      this.value = this.value.toLowerCase();
      input = $(this).val();
      console.log("dentro de keyup: " + input);
    })
  }
  
  input = getUserInput();
  console.log(input);
  setInterval(function(){ console.log("fuera de keyup: " + input); }, 3000);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="user-input" id="contenido-post" placeholder="Tu texto aquí"></textarea>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta tan bien explicada y tan rápido. El caso es que necesito que el valor de la variable input se actualice en tiempo real (igual que en el console log de dentro de la función) en el global scope para posteriormente hacer un append a otro textarea de sólo lectura. Acabo de empezar con esto y no logro entender porqué poniendo el setInterval si que da el valor esperado y sin ponerlo no.

Comment: @MarcTorrents y no te vale hacer el `append` del otro `textarea` dentro del `keyup`? En lugar de coger y guardar en `input` y luego hacer `append`?

Comment: @AdrianJM  al final es lo que he hecho y perfecto. Gracias!